# training images? Considerations for selection

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, object-detection

I'm relatively new and am still learning the basics. I've used NVIDIA DIGITS in the past, and am now looking at Tensorflow. While I've been able to fumble my way around creating some models for a few projects I'm working on, I really want to start diving deeper into what I'm doing, how I'm doing it, and ultimately a better understanding of why.

One area that I would like to start with is the Images that I'm using for training and testing. Can anyone point me to a blog, an article, a paper, or give me some insight in what I need to consider when selecting images to train a new model on. Up until recently, I've been using datasets that have already been selected and that are available for download. Lets say I'm going to start working on a project that involves object detection of ships from a variety of distances and angles.

So my thoughts would be

1) I need a large quantity of images.
2) The images need to contain ships of the different types I would like to detect. (lets just say one class, ships, don't care what type of ships)
3) I also need to have images that have a great variety of distance perspective for the different types of ships.

Ultimately, my thoughts are that the images need to reflect the distance, perspective, and types of ships I would ideally want to identify from the video. Seems simple enough.

However, there are a number of questions

Does the images need to be the same/similar resolution as the camera I'll be using, for best results?
Does the images all need to be the same resolution?
Can I use a single image and just digitally zoom out on the image to give the illusion of different distances?

I'm sure there are a number of other questions that I'm not asking, or should be asking. Are there any guide lines available for creating a solid collection of images to use when creating the collection of images for training and validation?

Comment: Your question doesn't fit here particularly well, but is a worthy question.  Please check ["Which site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in) for general issues.

Comment: I actually attempted this question on Tensorflow site and they sent me here. I really got to get better at determining which site to use.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend thinking through end to end, like would you need to classify ship models as a next step? I recommend going through well known public datasets and actually work with the structure, how to store data, labels, how to handle preprocessing etc.

More importantly, what are you trying to achieve? Talking to experts in the topic does help greatly while preparing your own dataset.

Use open source images if you can, e.g. flickr, google, imagenet.

No, you don't need them to be the same resolution.

It is not ideal to zoom in/out images to use in different categories. Preprocessing images and data augmentation already does this to create more distant representations of the same class. This is why I would recommend hands on approach with an existing dataset first.

Yes, what you need is many, different representations of classes, and a roughly balanced dataset of classes. If you define your data structure well in the beginning, it will save you a ton of time as you won't have to make changes often.

Comment: dusa thank you for the input. You make a lot of great points regarding the process and building a collection that may need to evolve. Right now I'm trying to think as simple as possible and build from there. Think of this question has my hello world of building an image collection for object detection.